# how to set sub-domain base url in CI?

Tags: codeigniter, base-url

In CI, currently I have base_url() as 'xxx.com'.Now as per requirements,every enterprise is treated as sub-domain with its own menu, content completely different from main site.Now for sub-domain, I want to set base_url() as 'enterprise.xxx.com'.

How am I supposed to do this dynamically.The sub-domain can be viewed via main site.

Comment: means do you wants to run some content from subdomain and some for main and codeigniter will be the same.. right..?

Comment: @SanjaySinalkar yes you are absolutely right. Only change will be in url. If from main site url will be 'xxx.com' but if from sub-domain url will be 'enterprise.xxx.com'. I have successfully retrieved the data related to related site(main site and sub site). 
My problem here is to dynamically add url for sub-site.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in `config/config.php`

```
$root=(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https://" : "http://").$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root.= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '',  $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

$config['base_url'] = $root;
```